# Access to font at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: wordpress

I have two problems in my website:

1) Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mywebsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://demo.kallyas.net/ares-furniture-interior-design/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/03/montserrat-light-webfont.woff'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

2) Access to font at 'https://kallyas.net/demo-ares/furniture/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/03/montserrat-light-webfont.woff' from origin 'https://www.mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I have tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

&

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
```

Answer (score 14):

**put this code in your .htaccess file** and try it

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add particular header to the server's response instructing the browser to allow fetching particular resource (font, image, etc.) by editing the `.htaccess` file in server root folder (or where your web site is):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css)$">
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

The regex line `(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css)` means that we will add this header to the response when serving files with such extensions **and** every CSS file, who begins with "font" and ends with "css" (the dot represent *any* character, because it is not escaped).

By my experience this is the most effective and simple way to solve the problem.

Comment: technically, the `font.css` regex shown matches any file that **ends** with `font`<any single character>`css`.  A better (?) regexp for a file that starts with `font` and ends with `.css` would be `^font.*\.css$`.